# Ajuda com PHP require_once

Tags: php

Tenho esse código para mudar de página

```
require_once(basename(($_GET[''page'']!='''' ? $_GET[''page''] : ''home'') . ''.php''));
```

Gostaria que ele pegasse os arquivos de uma página especifica tipo /inc/pages...

Comment: este pode ser o código mais inseguro que eu já vi postado aqui.

Comment: Mas, o que acontece? Dá erro? Não funciona? Por favor, especifique melhor a tua pergunta para que podemos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Bom se não é seguro me mostre um seguro.
Ele funciona sim, porem preciso de um que pegue os arquivos de outra pasta. É para a mudança de página

Comment: Ele funciona, porem preciso que ele obtenha as páginas de outras pastas como /inc/pages/ quero que os arquivos fiquem ai e não na pasta principal.

Comment: A solução segura é ter uma lista de quais são as páginas válidas, e verificar se o que o usuário passou está nessa lista. Porque do jeito que está, alguém mal-intencionado vai conseguir executar qualquer PHP que exista no projeto (e talvez até qualquer PHP que exista no servidor).

Comment: @Maniero só "não" é inseguro porque não executa - *syntax error*

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você deve estar tentando acessar arquivos e diretórios que o servidor Web não enxerga, principalmente por motivos de segurança. Se o diretório padrão para deploy dos arquivos é `/var/www` por exemplo, somente deste diretório para baixo será visível ao servidor. Você jamais conseguirá carregar algo de `/inc/pages`, a menos que mova `/inc/pages` para dentro de `/var/www`.